# How to add table to a specific Bigtable instance?

Tags: bigtable

Let's say I have three Bigtable instances `bt1`, `bt2` and `bt3`.

Now I want to add a table to `bt2`.

`cbt createtable t1`

Now that command cannot specify the instance and according to the documentation I need to put that into `~/.cbtrc`.

But I don't want to edit that file every time I need to add a table for another instance. Do I have to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify an instance with the -instance flag.

```
-project string
    project ID, if unset uses gcloud configured project
-instance string
    Cloud Bigtable instance
-creds string
    if set, use application credentials in this file
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-reference